# Progress bar loading twice webview

Tags: android, webview, progress

While i enter the url and press go this progress bar works perfectly fine but when i am accessing any url present in the webview it tend to load twice.Please give valuable suggestion.

```
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {      
MainActivity.this.setValue(newProgress);
super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
if (newProgress == 100) {
progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else{
progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
}
}
public void setValue(int progress) {
this.progress.setProgress(progress);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**onCreate:**

progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

**WebViewClient method on MainActivity**

```
private final WebViewClient mWebClient = new WebViewClient()
    {@Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            proyect.this.url.setText(url);
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. You can check if the progress dialog is null before loading it.

```
private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            if (dialog == null) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(sectionActivity, "",
                        "Loading. Please wait...", true);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }
    });
```